# R - extract row as character string with double quote

Tags: r, dataframe, character

I have a data frame called dataf

```
dataf<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,10,rep=TRUE)))
```

and I would like to extract each row of this data frame as a character string like with this function :

```
result=data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=1, nrow=10))

i=0
for(i in 0:9)
{
  result[i+1,]=toString(dataf[i+1,])
}
```

but result is not as expected :

```
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
```

I would like this:

```
"1","0","0","0","1","0","0","1","1","0"
"0","0","0","1","1","1","1","0","1","1"
"1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","1","0"
```

I already tried with `dQuote`, with `\"R\"`, with `collapse`, with `sep`... but I don't get what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:  `capture.output(write.table(lapply(dataf, as.character), row.names=F, col.names=F, sep=","))`

```
 [1] "\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\""
 [2] "\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\""
 [3] "\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\""
...
```

Edited in response to Matthew's comment below

Comment: Cool idea, unfortunately this only prints to screen. You can wrap it in `capture.output` to save to a variable.

Comment: YES ! Very nice! it works. Thank so much, so appreciated ! just another thing, sorry, do you know how to process with NA. Na are not with double quote.....

Comment: You could convert NAs to characters before you do the above - `dataf[is.na(dataf)] <- "NA"`

Answer (score 2):

This is another option, similar to @Phil's in approach, but gives the same output as @JayBlack.

```
apply(dataf, 1, function(.) paste(dQuote(.), collapse=','))
```

This returns the following vector of strings.

```
 [1] "\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\""
 [2] "\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\""
 [3] "\"1\",\"1\",\"0\",\"1\",\"0\",\"0\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\",\"1\""
 .....
```

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]

Here's a way:

```
d <- apply(dataf, 1, toString)
splitup <- lapply(d, function(x) paste('\"', unlist(strsplit(x, ',')), ',\"', sep=''))

data.frame(do.call(rbind, splitup))
     X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9
1  "1," " 0," " 0," " 1," " 1," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 1,"
2  "1," " 0," " 1," " 1," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 0," " 0,"
3  "0," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 0,"
4  "0," " 1," " 1," " 1," " 0," " 0," " 1," " 1," " 1,"
5  "1," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 1," " 1,"
6  "1," " 0," " 1," " 1," " 0," " 0," " 0," " 1," " 0,"
7  "1," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 0," " 1," " 1," " 1," " 1,"
8  "0," " 1," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 1," " 1,"
9  "1," " 1," " 1," " 0," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 1," " 0,"
10 "0," " 0," " 0," " 0," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 0," " 1,"
```

Comment: you're right. trying something else. I've seen it before on here, trying to remember.

Comment: thanks so much for help. I think we are close. But as you can see, we get this : "1," " 0," " 0," " 1," " 1," " 0," " 1," " 0," " 1,"  but I need this : "1", "0" ,"0","1","1","0","1","0","1"  I'll try to adapt your code. Thanks, it's so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Not the output you specified but may be useful to others?

```
apply(dataf, 1, paste0, collapse = "")
```

Yields:

```
[1] "0000000101" "0100100111" "1110101001" "1001010101" "1011111100" "1010000111"
[7] "0110001110" "1111000011" "1001101000" "0010011010"
```

Is that the output you hoped for?